# GTK apps no longer render text

Tags: ssh, debian, libvirt, virt-manager, gtk

I am using virt-manager on Debian Jessie. A few weeks ago, it was working fine for me; however now when I run it, the text does not render correctly.

[image: Virt-Manager font rendering issue]

I have tried reinstalling all of the dejavu fonts, liberation fonts, run fc-cache, rebooted the system, even reinstalled libvirt and virt-manager. No dice.

This issue is present both when using Xming via putty/ssh, and when doing ssh -Y from another linux box. The only thing I can remember doing that might have affected fonts is installing updates from apt.

Ideas welcome, need help here!

[EDIT] further research has shown that this is in fact a GTK problem; running non GTK x11 apps such as xfontsel works fine; running GTK stuff such as [this code](https://github.com/Programmica/python-gtk3-tutorial/blob/master/_examples/fontchooserdialog.py) does not. I still don't know how to solve it but hopefully this helps get somewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for some weird reason, libgtk seems to have become uninstalled. The issue has been fixed, by doing apt-get install libgtk-3-0. What on earth it was that caused it to become uninstalled, I know not. It seems bizarre to me that a GTK based application would even launch if libgtk was not installed - but there you go. We are back to working, hurrah!